# Window.Activate() not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Sometime, `Window.Activate()` not working in other system.

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(y => y.IsActive) ?? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault();
if (window != null) 
    window.Activate();
```

I  want a solution which should not fail in any system and also want to know the main cause of this.

Comment: You can try to toggle `window.Topmost = true; window.Topmost = false;` just before the `window.Activate();`. That could be a good workaround for those rare situations.

Answer (score 2):

It can fail if you call it from non-UI thread. In that case you should to wrap call into dispatcher.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{       
    ///.... UI stuff
});
```

Comment: Pretty weird, but for me only the `.BeginInvoke` worked.